# C++ Function that passes any function with any number of arguments

Tags: c++, function, templates, arguments

This may not be possible in c++, but I've search online and found nothing that seems to work.

I don't know how this works, but if I pass a function "A" to another function "B", I can execute function "B" in "A" like so:

```
template<typename Func>
void process(Func func) {
    func();
}

void myVoidFunction() {
    cout << "I did something!?" << endl;
}

process(myVoidFunction); // This will run myVoidFunction();
```

Now, I don't know how I would do this for a function with any number of arguments, my basic theory is this (I hope you know what I mean):

```
template<typename Func>
void process(Func func, ...) {
    func(...);
}

void myNewFunction(int, int, char*) {}

process(myNewFunction, 1, 2, "Hello World!");
```

Even better if process can return the same type as the given function (if thats not asking too much :P)

I don't want any libraries to do this, I'm sure there is a way using JUST C++. Please help :_|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++11, you could use variadic templates and perfect forwarding:

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
void process(Func func, Args&&...) {
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

For instance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
void process(Func func, Args&&... args) {
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

void myVoidFunction(std::string a, int b, double c) {
    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    process(myVoidFunction, "Hello", 42, 3.14);
}
```

See a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4oGKaO%2415).

Comment: Your answer and @ecatmur's are identical in essence, except that you have `Args&&... args`, while he has `Args... &&args` in the `process` signature. Are both acceptable?

Comment: I tried this a long time ago, tried playing with it, this straight up doesnt compile:

Comment: @Chowlett: No, he probably made a typo. Only `Args&&...` is syntactically correct.

Comment: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&&' token I'm using gnu gcc in codeblocks

Comment: @Luka: Which version? Also, are you compiling with the `-std=c++11` option? As you can see, in the live example I linked the code compiles and runs fine.

Comment: @AndyProwl Ok, it compiles when I let g++ follow the c++11 standard, but is this only possible with the c++11 standard, im curious to find that solution

Comment: @Luka: Well, a generic, elegant, and extensible solution is only possible with C++11's variadic templates. In C++03 you would have to define several overloads of `process()` to forward zero, one, two, ... up to some limited number of arguments. Moreover, you would also have to take care of forwarding arguments manually (when to use references vs passing by value), and you won't be able to get the benefit of move semantics. In short: I would switch to C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Use a variadic template:

```
template<typename Func, typename Args...>
void process(Func func, Args... &&args) {
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++11 gives two ways to do things like this.  One is variadic templates and the other is `std::bind`.  Without C++11, you're looking for `boost::bind` but you said no libraries.  That leaves you with either rolling your own version of `bind` or doing something like this:

```
template<typename Func> void process(Func func) { func(); }
template<typename Func, typename Arg1Type> void process(Func func, Arg1Type arg1) { func(arg1); }
template<typename Func, typename Arg1Type, typename Arg2Type> void process(Func func, Arg1Type arg1, Arg2Type arg2) { func(arg1, arg2); }
//etc.
```

`boost::function` and `boost::bind` look a lot like this.